# php startup error: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, apache, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have just setup a new apache server and i am getting this error, due to which php is not working

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ffmpeg.so
```

What should i do to get rid of this? would installing ffmpeg help?

Comment: Try to comment out the extension in your php.ini if you dont need this extension

Comment: the problem is that i dont see ffmpeg.so in the php.ini file

Comment: The you can try to install this extension. Also you should to figure out if you are editing the correct php.ini